# Custom aspx page to CRM 2011

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am new to the CRM 2011
what is the correct way to add an aspx page
because many advises to add an HTML page and a silverlight component to the web resource

is it  the best way ?

Answer (score 5):

adding an ASPX Page is not the best way to add custom views on CRM data anymore.

If you only want a custom way to display crm data, using webresources is a better way, as these will also work on offline clients, and are integrated with the solution model -> better deployment experience.

Use the REST endpoint to retrieve and update data in CRM.

Silverlight or not is up to the requirements you have. You can also do a lot if you use HTML and JScript, maybe in combination with JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an ASPX page or site, you could add it as an IFrame (display it inside an entity) or add it to the left menu (display it across the whole entity) or the ribbon toolbar (open in new window).

Answer (score 0):

You can use .aspx page and using ribbon button you called it or using IFRAME You can call it.I have done it as long as you aspx page host server is working i have not had any issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you WANT do it , you can put your ASPX pages into ISV folder .
If your ASPX use any DLL files ,put them into CRMWEB\Bin folder .